# The set of primes as the spectrum of a first-order theory

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

In model theory, the finite spectrum of a first-order sentence $\phi $ (in a language with arbitrarily many constants, functions and relations is defined as the set of natural numbers $ n$ such that $\phi $ has a model with exactly $ n $ elements.

How can I show that the set of primes is a spectrum for a sentence $\phi $?

My first idea was to take the theory of fields and augment it by some symbols and theorems excluding the fields of order $ p^n $ with $ n > 1$, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I *think* we've had this question before.

Comment: While this is a duplicate, the hint at the older problem is not really more than what this OP here as already tried. It would be nice to have a stronger hint.